# Postgresql case where if in one group can't belong to another

Tags: postgresql

For some reason I am struggling with what should be quite a basic thing. I have users who have projects with multiple actions in them. I would need to divide project into two groups based on if one action has happened in the project even once. If action "scanned" has happened then project is "scanned" and all the other projects are "not_scanned".

Example of the data:

```
user_id    project_id    action

012081f     9a5a30e     modified
012081f     9a5a30e     loaded
012081f     9a5a30e     saved  
03011d2     246b52e     scanned
03011d2     246b52e     loaded 
03011d2     246b52e     saved 
04345a6     afb63ef     modified 
04345a6     afb63ef     modified
04345a6     afb63ef     scanned
```

What I would like end up with:

```
user_id    project_id   project_type    

012081f     9a5a30e     not_scanned       
03011d2     246b52e     scanned
04345a6     afb63ef     scanned
```

I have tried with case but because same project has many lines with different actions the project_id ends up to be in both not_scanned and scanned group

```
select 
    user_id,
    project_id,
    case    
        when action = 'scanned' then 'scanned'
        else 'not_scanned'
    end as project_type
from base_table
where user_id is not Null
group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many different options to solve this issue, two examples:

```
SELECT  user_id
    ,   project_id
    ,   COALESCE((ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT action) FILTER(WHERE action = 'scanned'))[1], 'not_scanned')
FROM    base_table
GROUP BY
    1,2;
```

Another option is to use DISTINCT ON:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (user_id,project_id)
        user_id
    ,   project_id
    ,   CASE WHEN action <> 'scanned' THEN 'not_scanned'
        ELSE action
        END AS action
FROM    base_table
ORDER BY
        user_id
    ,   project_id
    ,   action <> 'scanned';
```

And there are probably more ways to solve this issue, maybe smarter or faster.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying also with COALESCE but had a minor mistake there and couldn't get around. This seems to solve the problem for now.

Comment: If the answer provided resolved your issue then please accept it. This helps future questioners having the same or similar issues. It also removes the question from the *unanswered* queue. Kindly do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.